# Google universal analytics detects the payment/authorization terminal as the referral

Tags: php, e-commerce, universal-analytics, 3d-secure

When the customer selcts Visa/Mastercard as the payment method, they're sent to an external payment terminal to make the actual payment (NETS BBS). After inputting their card data they're then sent to an authorization terminal (3D Secure), if their bank supports it, to verify their payment. At the end they're sent back and is presented with a "Thank you" page. And this is where the google ecommerce tracker is executed.

But what happens is that "mpi1.3dsecure.no" gets detected as the referral. This is the authorization terminal where the customer verified their payment. This is to some degree correct since it's where they entered the "Thank you" page from, but is not what we're looking for. We want to know where the customer came from into the site to begin with.

Has anyone wxperienced this behaviour, and know of a workaround to this?

Tried to put the google code before being sent to the external payment site, but that can provide unaccurate results since not all payment succeeds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the property settings and add your payment gateway to the referral exclusion list (won't change data already recorded but should fix the problem for future transactions).